# INICIALIZAR LOS CAMPO AUTO NUMERICO (ACCESS)

Tags: vba

Estoy intentando inicializar el campo autonumerico de un campo llamado idPaciente con atributo auto numerico 1- elimino el campo y lo vuelvo a introducir (NO FUNCIONA)   2- Hago un diseño de consulta llamando a la tabla , especificando en que nro. va a comenzar (0) por que la acabo de vaciar y coloco el campo (DA ERROR) si por favor alguien me presta su colaboracion

Comment: Comparte tu código por favor o poco se te podrá ayudar

Comment: No. no estoy usando codigo, lo estoy acciendo desde la parte operativa de access, gogleando tengo entendido que no se puede hacer con codigo. (CREO)

Comment: Entonces cambia la etiqueta, quita vba y pon ms-access.

Comment: Si no usas código ¿porqué pones la etiqueta `vba`? En todo caso sí que puedes usar código, usando `vba` precisamente sería una forma.

Comment: Tienes razon voy a tratar de reformularla de otra forma. Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes alterar el contador del campo autonumerico  usando SQL :

> sub reiniciarautonumber
>
> misent = "ALTER TABLE mitabla ALTER COLUMN micol COUNTER(1, 1);"
>   CurrentProject.Connection.Execute misent
>
> end sub

Si te da algun problema , me dices 
Saludos

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda , me sirve asi